# Copiar elementos de un arraylist a un hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

La intención es pasar todos los datos de un hashmap a un arraylist, ordenar este por un atributo que se llama fortaleza y luego poner los elementos ya ordenados de ese arraylist de nuevo al hashmap. Para ello busco el ID en el arraylist que es la key del hashmap pero me dice que no la puede encontrar. Entiendo que es un error de sintaxis pero no lo sé solucionar.
Muchas gracias. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public List<Entry<String,Criatura>> ordenarPorFortaleza(){
    List<Entry<String,Criatura>> mapaCriaturas2 = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Criatura>>(mapaCriaturas.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(mapaCriaturas2,Criatura.FortalezaComparator);
    mapaCriaturas.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i<mapaCriaturas2.size(); i++){
      mapaCriaturas.put(mapaCriaturas2.get(i).getID(),mapaCriaturas2.get(i));
    }
    return mapaCriaturas2;
  }
```

Comment: Mejor usa un `TreeMap` y te ahorras la maroma.

Comment: No me permiten usarlo para practicar, por eso tengo que hacer todo eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, lo que te ocurre es que tienes un error de concepto con el uso de la clase `HashMap`. Esta clase almacena los elementos NO ORDENADOS y esto no se puede cambiar, puesto que internamente utiliza el HASH de las claves para determinar donde almacena cada elemento. Esto lo hace para ganar en redimiento sobre todo en operaciones de búsquedas. Por lo tanto lo que intentas hacer no lo vas a lograr nunca.

Ahora, respecto a tu error específico el problema está en que tu lista contiene instancias de `Entry` y no de `Criatura`. Por lo tanto, si quieres acceder a la criatura primero tienes que pedir el valor que almacena la `Entry`.

```
Criatura criatura = mapaCriaturas2.get(i).getValue();
mapaCriaturas.put(criatura.getID(), criatura);
```